# Why access_token on twitter's streaming API?

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I am trying to set up a cache service and take use of the streaming api of Twitter. It confuses me, since this is a server-to-server use, why do I still need to use an `access_token` when no user are involved in the process, only the application?

Answer (score 0):

So Twitter can have information on how are their API and services being used. Also, to prevent DoS and other kind of attacks

Comment: Authentication of a user doesn't really make any sense though, does it? The application itself should be able to set up a streaming API even if no users are authenticated with it.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the token they ask for is your application's, not every user's.

Comment: You do need the app token and the user token to establish a connection with the streaming API unfortunately.